# Disable ATI Radeon HD 6950 In ubuntu, not in BIOS?

Tags: ati, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have the Radeon HD 6950 which have very poor linux support. Instead of running Unity 2d or any other, I would rather use my old 8800GTS which works great, and then disable the 6950 since I only need the 6950 for gaming in windows anyways.

So my question; In Windows I can disable the 8800 GTS in the device manager, but how do I do the same thing in ubuntu, just for the 6950.

I have read about hybrid graphic cards in laptops, but I don't think this is the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "blacklist" the device such that it is not activated when you boot into linux. 
This is done by adding the device to this file **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**.
To find out which module you have to put there search with `lsmod | grep -e radeon -e ati`.

Comment: the disabling works, but once I disable the ATI card, I'm not able to get past the bootscreen. If I move the 8800 to the first PCI slot it seems to work, but then the 6950 won't work in windows. So either way, it doesn't seems to be possible.

Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Press CRTL-E in grub on startup menu to enter the bootloader entry and add **nomodeset** after **quiet splash**. Try that first for the recovery mode and see whether that allows you to get to the bash to reinstall graphics. The command nomodeset will not allow any graphics drivers to kick in until the end of the boot process - that helped me once when I needed to get rid of nouveau to install my nVidia card.